# Change values of columns on conditional bases (Missing Data and Categorical)

Tags: r, vector, transform, apply, na

For a questionnaire I want to make a copy of df1 where the following two things happen with column x:

1. Replace missing data of x (which is coded as 0) for '-1'. So all the 0 must become -1.
2. A specific part of x is coded in numbers instead of categories. I created a function to assign different categories to different values

```r
categorise <- function(a_vector) { a_vector = case_when(
        a_vector >= 0 & a_vector < 50 ~ 1,
        a_vector >= 50 & a_vector < 500 ~ 2,
        a_vector >= 500 & a_vector < 5000 ~ 3,
        a_vector >= 5000 & a_vector < 50000 ~ 4,
        a_vector >= 50000 & a_vector < 500000 ~ 5,
        a_vector >= 500000 & a_vector < 5000000 ~ 6,
        a_vector >= 5000000 & a_vector < 50000000 ~ 7,
        a_vector >= 50000000 & a_vector < 500000000 ~ 8)
        strong texta_vector }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write the `categorise_losses` function like this:

```r
categorise_losses <- function(x)
  as.integer(log10(x / 5)) + 1L

# an example of using the function
categorise_losses(c(1L, 10L, 65L, 250L, 555L, 5000L))
#R> [1] 1 1 2 2 3 4

# compare with the OP's function
library(dplyr)
categorise_losses_OP <- function(x)
  case_when(
    x >= 0 & x < 50 ~ 1,
    x >= 50 & x < 500 ~ 2,
    x >= 500 & x < 5000 ~ 3,
    x >= 5000 & x < 50000 ~ 4,
    x >= 50000 & x < 500000 ~ 5,
    x >= 500000 & x < 5000000 ~ 6,
    x >= 5000000 & x < 50000000 ~ 7,
    x >= 50000000 & x < 500000000 ~ 8)

# we get the same
all.equal(categorise_losses_OP(1:500000), 
          categorise_losses   (1:500000))
#R> [1] TRUE
```

To handle the condition that 0 becomes -9, then you can use:

```r
categorise_losses <- function(x)
  suppressWarnings(ifelse(x == 0, -9L, as.integer(log10(x / 5)) + 1L))

categorise_losses(c(0L, 1L, 10L, 65L, 250L, 555L, 5000L))
#R> [1] -9  1  1  2  2  3  4
```

To use the function on a subset of column entries, you can use the `$` to access the column and then use `[]` to subset the entries you need like this:

```r
# data set example
dat <- data.frame(year = c(1950L, 1950L, 1950L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L), 
                  crop_loss = c(0L, 5L, 95L, -9L, -9L, 1L))

# use the function on the data
categorise_losses <- function(x)
  suppressWarnings(ifelse(x == 0, -9L, as.integer(log10(x / 5)) + 1L))

dat$crop_loss[dat$year <= 2006L] <- 
  categorise_losses(dat$crop_loss[dat$year <= 2006L])

# the result
dat
#R>   year crop_loss
#R> 1 1950        -9
#R> 2 1950         1
#R> 3 1950         2
#R> 4 2010        -9
#R> 5 2010        -9
#R> 6 2010         1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer! I'm beginner with R so i'm not really sure how to apply your codes above. I've added a part of the dataset and the some conditions in my question. Can you help me to write the right code? Thanks in forward!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `findInterval`

```
replace(findInterval(a_vector, c(0, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, 
      500000, 5000000, 50000000)), a_vector == 0, -9)
#[1] -9  1  1  2  2  3  4
```

---

Or with `cut`

```
as.integer(cut(a_vector, breaks =  c(0, 50, 500, 5000, 50000, 500000, 5000000, 50000000)))
```

#### data

```
a_vector <- c(0L, 1L, 10L, 65L, 250L, 555L, 5000L)
```

Comment: Thank you! And for changing the '0' with '-9'?